# AS3 to php create online folder

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have a AS3 flash app that needs to create a folder/path (online) for each user, and get some xml files inside these folders.

I can get the php to write these xml files, but only if the path/folder already exists. If it doesen't, then it returns an error:

```
[<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/edicoes/public_html/test//savexml.php on line 20
```

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$XMLFile = $_POST["xmlfile"];
$filename = $_POST["filename"];

//mkdir($User, '0777'); //I tried mkdir, to no avail. It's only for offline?

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $XMLFile );
fclose($handle);

echo "result=success";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create the directory first. Make sure apache have the rights to create dir in parent dir (chmod 777).

What if someone call your code with :
xmlfile = malicious php code
filename = something.php
and then call the php page with a browser ?

You should care about security, at least add the ".xml" extension in php code.

Comment: Do I have to manually create each folder? I wanted the code to do a folder automatically to each user if it didnt existed. Also I am aware of code injection problems, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The mkdir code you wrote should be ok no ? if $User is not null

Comment: Okay, my bad. I was using the wrong sintax and assumed it didn't work for online paths. Was using just "test" as the $User, changed it to "./test" and started working. Thank you.